How to wait for a threaded api to finish?
I have this api that takes some inputs, and the code only has this line (except the import demo_v1 line):
demo_v1.main(image file, text file, integer)
Instead of manually writing the inputs for different scenarios, I wanted to run this in a for loop, so that all results will be given in a single run.
The issue is this api uses threads so my code continues before these threads finish working. This makes the code crash.
I checked the join or wait commands, but I am not able to reach the threads inside this api, so I could not use join or wait. What is a good way of dealing with this situation? Thank you.

I put  time.sleep() after calling the api. Seems like working now, but is this a good practice? Can it cause issues with threads inside the api?

Well, sleep causes some issues. The api runs as expected in the first run, but in the following runs of for loop, the results are not as expected. I tried one of following scenarios as the first run and the results are as expected. So sleep did not solve the issue.

"subprocess.call( )" from another script with arguments set by importing "argparse" solved the issue.
